# Implementing File Uploads From Angular to Flask

Tags: python, angular, forms, flask, upload

I am trying to implement file uploading for my Web tool. The front end is developed using angular and the back end is using flask. Following tutorials on the flask website I have set up the following flask app:

```
from flask import Flask, request
from werkzeug import secure_filename
import os

UPLOAD_FOLDER = '/home/openstack/Documents/Confmrg/bcknd/uploads'

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'] = UPLOAD_FOLDER

@app.route('/uploader' , methods = ['GET' , 'POST'])
def upload_file():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        f = request.files['file']
        filename = secure_filename(f.filename)
        f.save(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], filename))
    return 'File Uploaded'


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug = True)
```

I run this and the web server is hosted on http://localhost:5000

So on my angular component html I place the following:

```
<form action="http://localhost:5000/uploader" method="POST" enctype = "multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" name="file" />
<input type="submit" />
</form>
```

However when I run the angular web page, and test it by uploading a file and clicking submit, nothing happens. There is no error, and nothing is output in the console. I must be missing something, could someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Form onSubmit handler

To answer your immediate question, what's happening is `input type submit` in Angular [calls the onSubmit method of the form](https://angular.io/guide/forms#submit-the-form-with-ngsubmit) (instead of submitting the form like in plain HTML). And because you don't have a handler for onSubmit in your class, nothing is happening.

For a quick test, follow [this link to create a simple onSubmit handler method](https://angular.io/guide/forms#submit-the-form-with-ngsubmit) to test that your submit button works.

Here's a Stackblitz example which logs to console when you click the submit button: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-uy481f

### File upload

To make file upload work, you would need to make a few things. This touches the component class, creating a new service and injecting it, and updating your form to bind it to the class.

1. Create a proper Angular form. [Here's an example](https://angular.io/guide/forms#create-a-form-component).
2. [Create a method](https://angular.io/guide/forms#submit-the-form-with-ngsubmit) that will handle the `onSubmit()` of the form.
3. Create a [service that will handle Http calls to upload files](https://angular.io/guide/http#making-a-post-request).
4. [Inject the service](https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt4#inject-the-heroservice) into your class, and call the file upload method of that class.

As you can see, there's a lot involved in making this work unlike having a simple post form in the template. As such, it will be too much for a single answer.

But hopefully, the initial paragraph answered your question and the rest of the answer pointed you in the right direction.

Comment: I have attempted to implement these, could you have a look at my followup question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59269915/assigning-a-file-to-a-variable-using-angular-forms-and-ngmodel